# iOS app crashes when attempting to edit a post with excessive code

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

I have attempted to edit [a post that happened to trigger an "excessively-long" auto-flag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79118/simple-win32-console-library-mimicking-almighty-sfml). In this case, it contained code within a single block. As soon as the editor comes up, the app stops responding and crashes after a few seconds. I have tested this several times and it has occurred each time.  However, this does *not* occur in the browser (the Chrome app, at least).

- iOS version: 8.1.3 (latest)
- App version: 1.2.2 (latest)

Comment: For me it's crashing when viewing that question, before even trying to edit. (so this got nothing to do with editor, more likely it's trying to render the code block)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think it lags a bit for me, but it doesn't crash (or perhaps I'm not waiting long enough before starting an edit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a low memory crash for two reasons:

1. You and Shadow Wizard are seeing crashes, I'm not getting crash reports, and [apparently Crashlytics can't tell me about low memory crashes](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/123408-do-you-catch-out-of-memory-crashes).
2. I just profiled looking at the question and saw this:

   [image: profiling the memory usage of looking at the editor, explained as follows]

The editor text view is ordering up a ridiculous amount of memory in order to even get you started. Memory usage jumps up by about 240MB rendering that monster occasionally form a steady state of ~300MB to 420MB on certain changes.  It is possible that we can get that down some if we drastically restructure the editor but I think the answer is that the editor doesn't support excessively long text.

Not sure what the remedy should be since we don't know what reasonable cutoffs are for each device.  My 6 for example was slow but able to make some changes and render a preview.  A 6+ might not be because of the increased screen density, a 4S might not be because of less available memory with a roughly equal drawing area.

Comment: I must've disregarded the memory side of things, and that these devices don't have oodles of RAM.  I first viewed the question via PC after seeing the flag, then later tried to edit the question via iPhone.  Had I not done this on the PC first, I probably wouldn't have had the chance to first discover that the question had excessive text.