# Animated Gif Crashes iOS App

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

Is it just me that crashes when viewing [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102225/jacks-or-better) on the iPhone app? I can view the page fine in Chrome, but every time I navigate to this page in the app, it crashes. Can anyone reproduce?

iPhone 6; iOS 8.4.1; App 1.3.2

Comment: Do you get any sort of error message? If yes, please add the screenshot / write it in the post.

Comment: No @HackerKarma. Just an app *crash*.

Comment: Confirmed this bug on the latest beta.

Comment: SE uses Crashlytics and crash reports will be automatically reported back to them.Meanwhile, [try this](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-an-iOS-App-Developer-a-Crash-Report) and see it shows anything.

Comment: No-repro in 1.3.2.218 (beta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just hit a special category of bug, viewing a post that straight up consumes all available memory and forces the OS to terminate the app.  [Here's another such example.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247856/ios-app-crashes-when-attempting-to-edit-a-post-with-excessive-code?rq=1)

This kind of crash is the worst because there's no way Crashlytics, or even Apple, can generate a meaningful bug report and there's really no way for us to avoid it.  We just have to live with it.

Fun graphs:

Just a UIWebView rending the desktop version:

[image: memory spiking at 50%]

You'll notice that the memory maxes out at half of the available RAM.

Throw in a the fact we're scaling the image, holding multiple web views, keeping more web view layers in memory than we probably should, etc, the real app looks more like this when displaying the image:

[image: Real app peaking at 80% memory]

This second graph hits 80% memory usage, just in the app, so it's no wonder that the OS would kill it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for looking into it Brian. It's nice to know what caused it, even if it's a [can't-fix].